# Get Destination URLs from AdsInsights graph api

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am using the Facebook ads SDK for Python, and have gone through the quick start setup, and I have a working example of how to get some data from the Insights API. But I am not able to figure out how to get what I really want.

What I want is to get all the landing pages for my ads, that have been either clicked or for ads that have some impressions. The idea behind this is to get all the landing pages so I can check if they are correct.

This is the example of the code I have right now, but I am not able to figure out the breakdown and fields stuff to get the result I want.

```
from facebookads.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebookads.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi

access_token = "my_token"

ad_account_id = 'act_XXXXXXXXXX'
app_secret = 'my_app_secret'
app_id = 'my_app_id'
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token)

fields = [
    'actions'

]
params = {
    'level': 'campaign',
    'filtering': [],
    'action_breakdowns': ['action_link_click_destination'],
    'time_range': {'since':'2018-01-17','until':'2018-02-16'},
}
print (AdAccount(ad_account_id).get_insights(
    fields=fields,
    params=params,
))
```

I have tried to look at the documentation here, but I am still not able to understand how to solve this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/breakdowns/ I have seen other 3rd party tools that get the landing pages from the Graph API so I am sure it can be done.

Hope someone can help me out

Comment: I would suggest looking at the object_story_spec at the ad level to get the destination URLs of your ads